# Finding the maximum of a gradient vector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, vector-calculus

Im trying to find the maximum of my gradient vector G[x,y], I've tried several options including FindMaximumValue, FindMaximum etc. but i couldn't find it.

The full function is shown below, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
G[x_,y_]:= {-5.4 E^(-2.25 ((-4 + x)^2 + (-2.5 + y)^2)) (-4 + x) - 
  6.4 E^(-4 ((-3.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-3.5 + x) - 
  8 E^(-4 ((-3 + x)^2 + (-3.5 + y)^2)) (-3 + x) - 
  9. E^(-9 ((-2.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-2.5 + x) - 
  5.5125 E^(-3.0625 ((-2 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2)) (-2 + x) - 
  1.8 E^(-(-1 + x)^2 - (-1 + y)^2) (-1 + x) - 
  30. E^(-25 ((-0.75 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2)) (-0.75 + 
     x), -8 E^(-4 ((-3 + x)^2 + (-3.5 + y)^2)) (-3.5 + y) - 
  5.5125 E^(-3.0625 ((-2 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2)) (-3 + y) - 
  5.4 E^(-2.25 ((-4 + x)^2 + (-2.5 + y)^2)) (-2.5 + y) - 
  30. E^(-25 ((-0.75 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2)) (-2 + y) - 
  6.4 E^(-4 ((-3.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-1.5 + y) - 
  9. E^(-9 ((-2.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-1.5 + y) - 
  1.8 E^(-(-1 + x)^2 - (-1 + y)^2) (-1 + y)}
```

Comment: G[x,y] is not scales quantity. What do you mean by maximum of gradient vector?

Comment: If you plot  Plot3D[G[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] you get a bunch of lumps, i want to find the "peaks"

Comment: note that, Plot3D[G[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] is actually a 3D plot if two functions. you can see it clearly from the plot. in this case you can find the max of each function separately, Maximize[G[x, y][[1]], {x, y}], Maximize[G[x, y][[2]], {x, y}].

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is helpful (if I interpret your aim correctly):
This is a little more challenging for your particular function.

```
g[x_, y_] := {-5.4 E^(-2.25 ((-4 + x)^2 + (-2.5 + y)^2)) (-4 + x) - 
   6.4 E^(-4 ((-3.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-3.5 + x) - 
   8 E^(-4 ((-3 + x)^2 + (-3.5 + y)^2)) (-3 + x) - 
   9. E^(-9 ((-2.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-2.5 + x) - 
   5.5125 E^(-3.0625 ((-2 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2)) (-2 + x) - 
   1.8 E^(-(-1 + x)^2 - (-1 + y)^2) (-1 + x) - 
   30. E^(-25 ((-0.75 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2)) (-0.75 + 
      x), -8 E^(-4 ((-3 + x)^2 + (-3.5 + y)^2)) (-3.5 + y) - 
   5.5125 E^(-3.0625 ((-2 + x)^2 + (-3 + y)^2)) (-3 + y) - 
   5.4 E^(-2.25 ((-4 + x)^2 + (-2.5 + y)^2)) (-2.5 + y) - 
   30. E^(-25 ((-0.75 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2)) (-2 + y) - 
   6.4 E^(-4 ((-3.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-1.5 + y) - 
   9. E^(-9 ((-2.5 + x)^2 + (-1.5 + y)^2)) (-1.5 + y) - 
   1.8 E^(-(-1 + x)^2 - (-1 + y)^2) (-1 + y)}
```

For simplicity maximizing $g(x,y).g(x,y)$ yields:

```
ma = Maximize[g[x, y].g[x, y], {x, y}]
```

yields: {0.595965, {x -> 1.1506, y -> 0.309118}}

However, you function has a lot of local maxima and minima. After looking at plot and choosing region of interest:

```
nma = NMaximize[{g[x, y].g[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 2}, {x, y}]
```

yields: {8.14402, {x -> 0.607423, y -> 2.}}

Showing this interactively (the red mesh lines intersect at the first maximum and the green at the second):

```
gr = Manipulate[
  Plot3D[g[x, y].g[x, y], {x, -1, 4}, {y, -1, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, r},
    MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #1 &, #2 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{ma[[2, 1, 2]]}, {ma[[2, 2, 2]]}, {nma[[2, 1, 
        2]]}, {nma[[2, 2, 2]]}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, Red, Green, Green}], {r, 1, 9}]
```

[image]

You can also visualize working backwards. A function whose gradient field is $g(x,y)$:

```
exp = (f[x, y] /. 
    First[DSolve[Thread[{D[f[x, y], x], D[f[x, y], y]} == g[x, y]], 
      f[x, y], {x, y}]]) /. C[1] -> 0;
```

Plotting candidate maximal gradients:

[image]

Or perhaps more instructively with `ContourPlot` and `StreamPlot` (reassuringly exp is consistent with gradient):

```
pt = Point[{x, y} /. ma[[2]]]
ptn = Point[{x, y} /. nma[[2]]]
cp = ContourPlot[exp, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 5}];
sp = StreamPlot[g[x, y], {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 5}];
Show[cp, sp, 
 Graphics[{{PointSize[0.02], Red, pt}, {PointSize[0.02], Green, 
    ptn}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Any reason why the contour plot is over $[-1,5]\times[-1,5]$ while the streamline plot is only over $[-1,4]\times[-1,4]$?

Comment: @RahulNarain...tiredness...sorry...flat outside the mountains and fiddled to get them on....does not change the interpretation but will check when I get time

Comment: @RahulNarain have edited...